# Laravel / VueJs 2 Latest changes not rendering on live server IONOS

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I am working on Laravel / VueJs (version 2) and when I uploaded my files to the live server it WORKED! awesome, BUT the problem is now I am making changes to components and added more features that are working on my local, and when I uploaded those files to live again it doesn't show new changes. still showing older things... any idea how to fix that, please? I am stuck on this for 2 days
I have checked by clearing browser cache, hard reload, cookies

**NOTE:** I also uploaded files after running `npm run dev` and `npm run watch` but no success :(

**My Welcome.blade.php**

```
    <div id="app" >
        <main-component></main-component>
    </div>
    <script src="{{mix('js/app.js')}}" ></script>
```

**Webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .version();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, answering so anyone in the future could get help maybe.
as I was having a server cache issue so `version` laravel will not work here... I have changed how my assets loaded

```
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js?v='.time())}}" ></script>
```

compiled assets again by running `npm run production` and reuploaded `public` folder